# kubernetes deployments or pods on port 8080 result in 504 error

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I have a bit of a problem, I am trying to access a Keycloak pod through an ingress and I keep getting a 504 error
I have tried other deployments (nginx, apache, pg-admin) and they all work. The common aspect is that those pods run on port 80 and keycloak runs on port 8080. I have also tried to deploy apache airflow and by default port 8080 is used.
I can't set port 80 or 443 on the Keycloak deployment, I get the following error:

```
keycloak 06:23:59.51 ERROR ==> An invalid port was specified in the environment variable KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT: privileged port requested.
keycloak 06:23:59.51 ERROR ==> An invalid port was specified in the environment variable KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT: privileged port requested.
```

ingress-nginx-controller pod log:

```
10.7.211.10 - - [06/Jan/2022:05:57:42 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 504 562 "http://api.cp.ca/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36" 367 15.003 [default-kcd-8080] [] 10.244.1.59:8080, 10.244.1.59:8080, 10.244.1.59:8080 0, 0, 0 5.001, 5.000, 5.004 504, 504, 504 8c0c75ee66bebace840c4f77e5722c77
```

I have not firewall set anywhere, my cluster is made up 3 worker nodes, I am not using the cloud, just 4 virtual machines.

current configuration:

- MetalLB v0.11.0
- Kubernetes v1.22.4
- Flannel v0.15.11

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: tools-pgadmin
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: api.cp.ca
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kcd
                port:
                  number: 8080
# service:
# kubectl expose deployment kcd 
# kcd ClusterIP   10.109.12.99     <none>        8080/TCP,8443/TCP   8m18s

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kcd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: bitnami/keycloak
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        env:
          - name: DB_VENDOR
            value: "postgres"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST
            value: "10.7.211.100"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME
            value: "keycloak"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER
            value: "postgres"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD
            value: "postgres"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SCHEMA
            value: "public"
```

What can cause port 8080 not to be reached?
Are there any other settings to enable when building a stack from scratch?
thanks

Comment: It shouldn't matter on which port other apps are running. I would also try to create a pod inside given namespace and `curl` the keycloak pods directly to get any response.

Comment: I get host is unreachable
`wget 10.244.1.67:8080`
`Connecting to 10.244.1.67:8080 (10.244.1.67:8080)`
`wget: can't connect to remote host (10.244.1.67): Host is unreachable`
`/pgadmin4 $ wget 10.244.1.67:80`
`Connecting to 10.244.1.67:80 (10.244.1.67:80)`
`wget: can't connect to remote host (10.244.1.67): Host is unreachable`

Comment: Where did you run this command? Also try using `telnet` if there's a different protocol to check connectivity/accessibility in general

Comment: I ran wget inside a pod within the same namespace

Comment: Do you think it might have something to do with the docker image and containerd?

Comment: There is a chance that something is with the `image` which @HarshManvar in his answer suggested to change on verified one. `containerd` doesn't seem to be an issue since as you mentioned everything else works just fine. + try removing the annotation with `ingressclass` and add it to spec as `.spec.ingressClassName: nginx`. But 504 mostly shows that service can be reached and something doesn't work on the service side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure that might due to you are using the bitnami image, still i would suggest trying with below deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.0
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_USER
          value: root
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
          value : "80"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
          value: "443"
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
          value : keycloak.harshmanvar.tk #replace with ingress URL
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

File link : https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/keycload-deployment.yaml

Comment: `keycloak-6869b57cfd-qkqx4            1/1     Running   0          12m`
The pod runs, but I still get a 504

Comment: `Name:              keycloak
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=keycloak
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=keycloak
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.98.108.204
IPs:               10.98.108.204
Port:              port-1  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.67:8080
Port:              port-2  8443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.67:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>`
this is my service